# Sound output to bluetooth speaker stops when using youtube

Tags: 16.04, sound, dell, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a **UE Mini Boom** portable bluetooth speaker and a Dell Inspiron 3537 running **Ubuntu 16.04** LTS.

The speaker connects automatically to the laptop once paired and when I play songs locally on VLC there is no problem, but if I'm playing something on Youtube and there is some pause, buffering or if the autoplay counter starts, the audio will stop even though the video is playing. It will start playing only if I disconnect the speaker and reconnect it again, until the next pause.

This is the relevant (audio controller & bluetooth wireless interface) output from

> sudo lshw

```
description: Audio device
         product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:48 memory:c0810000-c0813fff


description: Audio device
         product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:50 memory:c0814000-c0817fff

description: Bluetooth wireless interface
         vendor: Atheros Communications, Inc.
         physical id: 5
         bus info: usb@1:1.5
         version: 0.02
         capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.10
         configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mAspeed=12Mbit/s
```

Here's the log from pulseaudio (as instructed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log) ) :

http://pastebin.com/qqaxYFDL

Is there anything that can be done to fix this?